# Recommended method for XML level loading in XNA

Tags: xna, c#, blender, xml

I want to use Blender as my level designer tool for an XNA game. Using an existing plugin, I can export my levels to DotScene format which is basically an xml file like this one:

```
<scene formatVersion="1.0.0">
  <nodes>
    <node name="scene-staircase.001">
      <position x="10.500000" y="1.400000" z="-9.600000"/>
      <quaternion x="0.000000" y="0.000000" z="-0.000000" w="1.000000"/>
      <scale x="1.000000" y="1.000000" z="1.000000"/>
      <entity name="scene-staircase.001" meshFile="staircase.mesh"/>
    </node>

    <node name="Lamp.003">
      <position x="11.024290" y="5.903862" z="9.658987"/>
      <quaternion x="-0.284166" y="0.726942" z="0.342034" w="0.523275"/>
      <scale x="1.000000" y="1.000000" z="1.000000"/>
      <light name="Spot.003" type="point">
        <colourDiffuse r="0.400000" g="0.154618" b="0.145180"/>
        <colourSpecular r="0.400000" g="0.154618" b="0.145180"/>
        <lightAttenuation range="5000.0" constant="1.000000" linear="0.033333" quadratic="0.000000"/>
      </light>
    </node>

    ...

  </nodes>
</scene>
```

Using naming conventions I could easily parse the file and load the correspondent in game content. I am new to XNA and I have seen that there are several methods to load XML files into a game like serializing and deserializing. Which one would you recommend?

Comment: I realized I can add my XML files as resources to the Content Manager specifying I don't want any binary conversion to take place and I want the files to get copied. Then, I can load the XML files as in a normal C# program.

Comment: If that's an answer you should put it in the answer section so that you can "accept" it and the question doesn't get bumped up because it's "unanswered".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually recommend using the newer XDocument class instead of XmlDocument. Check:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542073/xdocument-or-xmldocument

According to that thread it's also compatible with XBox and WP7, but I haven't tried since I'm currently developing for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I realized I can add my XML files as resources to the Content Manager specifying I don't want any binary conversion to take place and I want the files to get copied. Then, I can load the XML files as in a normal C# program:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(Content.RootDirectory + "\\XML\\file.xml");
```

Comment: Does this work on Xbox or WP7?

Comment: The answer is yes to both

Comment: Another option, is to create a custom content processor, which might be worth it, but is more involved.

Comment: The problem here is the loss of compression without the binary conversion.